# Can I upgrade a previously purchased iPhone under the iPhone Upgrade Program?

Tags: iphone, apple-store, iphone-upgrade-program

I bought an iPhone 6s Plus from Apple a couple of years ago. Can I enroll in the iPhone Upgrade Program and upgrade it to an iPhone 8/X?

Comment: Hi Ali, and welcome to Ask Different! Your question isn't really clear about what you're asking. Could you please update it with more details, like what you mean by upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: @Jackson1442 I meant the apple upgrade program

Answer (score 1):

Apple offers trade in for any phone you own outright. You have to pay monthly as part of an upgrade plan to get started, so unless you are paying Apple or the financing arranged through apple, you aren't part of the upgrade program which lets you get a new phone after 12 monthly payments.

You can easily check though - https://www.apple.com/shop/iphone/iphone-upgrade-program

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "upgrade" and what exact transaction you started a couple of years ago.

Comment: Better off selling your old device and using the money you get back for the new phone. Apple's trade in price very low

Comment: I paid in cash two years ago and i find website advertised by apple it estimated it for 190£ for good condition,  which i'd rather keep it than sell it for that price, as it's condition still as new and spec is equally to iphone 8 plus. I bought it for 700£ + 109 apple care